# Loaders on Fragments on the BackStack not retained

Tags: android, android-fragments

Recently I have been trying to make my Android App better with Caching Data from the server. After a bit of research I settled on the Loader Pattern as it takes care of a lot of situations for me.

Using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0`

I have managed to get the loaders to save the response when the device is rotated OR when the items are re-displayed when traversing back up the Back Stack.

The problem is when I place a few Fragments on the Activities Fragment Manager's Back Stack, rotate the device, then start back up the Back Stack.

These re-displayed Fragments's Loaders are recreated instead of using the loader from the first time they where displayed.

Here is the output from `LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true);`:

```
V/LoaderManager: initLoader in LoaderManager{8ddafd2 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}: args=null
V/LoaderManager:   Created new loader LoaderInfo{97187a0 #0 : DemoAppLoader{269af59}}
V/LoaderManager: Starting in LoaderManager{8ddafd2 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
V/LoaderManager:   Starting: LoaderInfo{97187a0 #0 : DemoAppLoader{269af59}}
D/DemoApp: MainActivity: -> http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts {"body":"Post 0: 
D/DemoApp: MainActivity: <- http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts {
                          "body": "Post 0: Nothing here!",
                          "title": "Fake 0",
                          "user_id": 0,
                          "id": 101
                        }
V/LoaderManager: onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{97187a0 #0 : DemoAppLoader{269af59}}
V/LoaderManager:   onLoadFinished in DemoAppLoader{269af59 id=0}: Response{fde91b}
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f75650179a0
V/LoaderManager: Stopping in LoaderManager{8ddafd2 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
V/LoaderManager:   Stopping: LoaderInfo{97187a0 #0 : DemoAppLoader{269af59}}
V/LoaderManager: initLoader in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}: args=null
V/LoaderManager:   Created new loader LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
V/LoaderManager: Starting in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
V/LoaderManager:   Starting: LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
D/DemoApp: MainActivity: -> http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts {"body":"Post 1: 
D/DemoApp: MainActivity: <- http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts {
                          "body": "Post 1: Nothing here!",
                          "title": "Fake 1",
                          "user_id": 0,
                          "id": 101
                        }
V/LoaderManager: onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
V/LoaderManager:   onLoadFinished in DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64 id=1}: Response{1cdb182}
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7565017a10
V/LoaderManager: Retaining in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
V/LoaderManager:   Retaining: LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Active in LoaderManager{8ddafd2 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
V/LoaderManager:   Destroying: LoaderInfo{97187a0 #0 : DemoAppLoader{269af59}}
V/LoaderManager:   Reseting: LoaderInfo{97187a0 #0 : DemoAppLoader{269af59}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{8ddafd2 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Active in LoaderManager{8ddafd2 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{8ddafd2 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{6208a3}}
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7565017930
V/LoaderManager: initLoader in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}: args=null
V/LoaderManager:   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
V/LoaderManager: Starting in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}
V/LoaderManager:   onLoadFinished in DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64 id=1}: Response{1cdb182}
V/LoaderManager: Finished Retaining in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}
V/LoaderManager:   Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
V/LoaderManager:   onLoadFinished in DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64 id=1}: Response{1cdb182}
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7565017cb0
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7565017460
V/LoaderManager: Stopping in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}
V/LoaderManager:   Stopping: LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Active in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}
V/LoaderManager:   Destroying: LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
V/LoaderManager:   Reseting: LoaderInfo{e87fbf7 #1 : DemoAppLoader{6b5ba64}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Active in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}
V/LoaderManager: Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{3e8cbf6 in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}
V/LoaderManager: initLoader in LoaderManager{b5dd22c in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}: args=null
V/LoaderManager:   Created new loader LoaderInfo{70414f5 #0 : DemoAppLoader{59dc28a}}
V/LoaderManager: Starting in LoaderManager{b5dd22c in HostCallbacks{5abbb3d}}
V/LoaderManager:   Starting: LoaderInfo{70414f5 #0 : DemoAppLoader{59dc28a}}
D/DemoApp: MainActivity: -> http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts {"body":"Post 0: 
D/DemoApp: MainActivity: <- http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts {
                          "body": "Post 0: Nothing here!",
                          "title": "Fake 0",
                          "user_id": 0,
                          "id": 101
                        }
V/LoaderManager: onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{70414f5 #0 : DemoAppLoader{59dc28a}}
V/LoaderManager:   onLoadFinished
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the 24.0.0 Support Library? Many fragment issues such as [this one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200927) were fixed in that release

Comment: Updating to 24.0.0 did fix the issue I was having. Unfortunately, it requires me to also update the project to JDK 8, which is a bit extreme, but I guess it is worth it. If you want to actually pose that as the solution, I will except it.

Comment: Yeah, compiling with API 24 (a requirement for using the v24 Support Library) requires Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of fragment issues such as [this related issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200927) were fixed in the [24.0.0 version](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#rev24-0-0). I suspect upgrading to that version will fix your issue.